# Getting error Call to undefined method CourseModel::deletecour() in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello developers i am getting error but don't know why? All thing is correct i think so. 
I am doing just simple delete in codeigniter using id.
Just check my code.

This is my controller.

```
public function deletecourse(){

        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $elete = array(
            'table'=>'ls_courses',
            'where'=>array('id'=>$id)
        );
        $result=$this->coursemodel->deletecour($elete);
        if($result){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfully deleted.');
        }
        else{
             $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Unable to delete data.Please try again.');
        }
        redirect(base_url().'admin/course/index/');
    }
```

This is Model function.

```
class CourseModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();          
    }
    public function deletecour($elete)
    {
        $this->db->where($elete['where']);
        return $this->db->delete($elete['table']);
     }  
   public function fetchCourseByParentID($id)
    {

    $this->db->select('course_name, image, sort_order, parent_id, 
    date_added, status');
    $this->db->from('ls_courses');
    $this->db->where('id = ' . $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if(!empty($query->result_array()))
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->db->error();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry brother it's $elete.

Comment: It is coming from my controller after getting id from uri. I make an array of $elete.

Comment: have you load `CourseModel`

Comment: Yes, in autoload i have done this $autoload['model'] = array('admin/coursemodel');

Comment: incorrect method for load module. right is `$autoload['model'] = array('coursemodel');`

Comment: But other function in my model is working fine so how can you say that it is incorrect.

Comment: Have you any other functions is this model?

Comment: Danish Ali brother i have added other function that i am using same on id. This function when i am calling from my controller is working fine.

Comment: before you try to call your method `deletecour` - try to output the name of the class - `var_dump(get_class($this->coursemodel));` and post whats in there - i suspect you overwrite your own variable somehow - beside the fact that you dont stick to the convention how to create a model (for that matter take a closer look here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model)

Comment: 1- in Codeigniter `Class Names` should start with an **uppercase letter**. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html

2- name your model file name also `uppercase starting` mode.

Comment: an other thing is that you can directly pass the $id as a function parameter. don't use $this->uri->segment(4)! because its load a library and calls a method in it. simply pass your id as function params.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Guys first of all thank you because you all replied very frequently to my question. I found the problem of my code. 
In my autoload.php i had passed the

$autoload['model'] = array('coursemodel','admin/coursemodel');

These are two different model but one for website and 2nd for admin side.
So when i was calling the model name. Problem is here with my model name which was clashing or you can say outside model was calling which is not for admin and there was no method named such as deletecour($elete).

So, that's why error was coming.
Thanks for your replies and sorry for wasting your time for this silly mistake.

$this->coursemodel->deletecour($elete);

Answer (score 0):

at your model ... 
name of your class is camel case.. in codeigniter documentation .. i have read somewhere to use underscore for naming classes with first later as capital ... change your model name from `CourseModel` to `Course_model` and try...

Comment: This is not the reason.

Comment: Manish ansari brother all functions in my model is working fine when i am calling the functions. But unfortunately why it is not working i don't know. Everything is correct. I checked it in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why it is happening ... but try to get all method available in your class... so you can find that ... why you are not able to call your method at model...

get all method available in your model

```
class CourseModel extends CI_Model 
{
public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();          
         var_dump(get_class_methods($this));
         EXIT;
    }
}
```